# Can't find ussage example of a simple query and having problems

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I'm trying to do something very simple.

I can't find any usage examples of PDO queries without paramaters.
mysqli was my fallback... trying to avoid MYSQL as everyone keeps complaining for me to not use it.

So I tried this:

```
$db = new mysqli('hostname', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=db", "user", "pass");
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$types = $db->query("SELECT * from `a_types` ORDER BY `priority`");
while ($type = $db->fetch_array($types)) {
echo '<a href="{$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]}?{$type[title]}=choose">I have a broken {$type[title]}.</a> <br />';
}
```

But I experience the following problem: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_array()`

What am I doing wrong?

**Also:** When I call `$db` do I have to close the connection after im finished with it? / how do I do so?

Comment: Why do you want to use both pdo and mysqli.

Comment: You didn't even run the query, how can you fetch anything ? If you do a `SELECT` query with PDO you usually close it with `$dbh->closeCursor();` .

Comment: $db->query means to run it right? or atleast thats how I do it with the mysql driver...

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Didn't see that.

Comment: @lgupta as i can't find any PDO examples that don't go use bind paramaters and as you can see my query does not need paramaters.

Comment: check out php docs http://ca2.php.net/pdo.query. First example does not use any params.

Comment: @lgupta but it doesn't show a select query or how to gather the results of the query.

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to call `fetch_array` on `$db` instead of on`$types`.
`$db->query()` returns a result-set which you are storing in `$types`. With this resut-set you can loop through the results using functions like `fetch_array`.

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT blabla');
while($type = $result->fetch_array()){
    // do stuff
}
```

// Edit: Its ofc always better to close a connection duo to more clean code. In general the connection is also closed when you delete the object (which also happens when the script is finished).

Comment: I dont really understand I wrote `$db->fetch_array($types)`; so surely it should be getting the results from the query attached to $types...?

Comment: Nope. The $db->query _returns_ the object you need to call `fetch_array` on. I will give you an example in a sec

Comment: This still didn't fix my probelm. It says its a non object whatever that means.

Comment: It means that the query function didnt return the object but **false**. Please check your php-error-log. The query function fails. So you maybe have an error in your sql

Comment: Had a tiny mistake in my example. It has to be $db->query ofc. Fixed it. Hope that wasnt the error you got :D

Comment: my problem is `$types = $db->query("SELECT * from `a_types` ORDER BY `priority`");
while ($type = $types->fetch_array()) {
echo '<a href="{$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]}?{$type[title]}=choose">I have a broken {$type[title]}.</a> <br />';
}` still gives `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object`

Comment: And I only can say: The code is right. Your query-method retuns not an object. That means (in fact) that the query fails and _that_ means that either your sql is wrong or your database connection invalid or the database is down or whatever

Comment: Check the $types-variable. If it is false, the query failed. You can get your error with `$db->error`

Answer (score 0):

Using Example #1 in [**PDO::query**](https://www.php.net/pdo.query) as commented by **Igputa**.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=db", "user", "pass");
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$types = $dbh->query("SELECT * from `a_types` ORDER BY `priority`");
$types->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($type = $types->fetch()) {
    echo '<a href="{$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]}?{$type[title]}=choose">I have a broken {$type[title]}.</a> <br />';
}
```